# I want to add one Newsletter subscribe button on my site; please help me as I have not used this in tridion so far

Tags: 2011, outbound-email, webforms

I am using tridion 2011, and I have to add one newsletter subscription button on a website. There will be one text box along with a button. User will fill in the email id in the textbox given and click on the subscribe button; with this he will be subscribed to the newsletter and on specific time each user clicked on subscribe button will be sent out the newsletter automatically.

I hope I made the requirement clear; I know that on click of the button I have to get the email id registered on main DB  by creating a contact; and on regular intervals the email will be sent to all contacts.

I don't now how to create contact in code on subscribe click; and how can I configure the newsletter and its automatic delivery to all contacts

Please help me.

Thanks;

Comment: Hello Dev and thanks for asking on Tridion Stack Exchange. How will you be manage emails and users in your solution? When you mention "main DB" or "contact" are those related to SDL's Audience Manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways you could do this.

If you have a license for SDL Audience Manager and Outbound E-mail, I would recommend using that. Audience Manager comes with sample ASP.NET and JSP pages that show how you can create a new Contact and sign them up for a newsletter.

You can then use [Triggered Mailings](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-00770A81-C4D9-4945-981C-D647EB586CB6) in Outbound E-mail to send out the newsletter automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried using the page subscription on local by adding it to a new project, I was not able to add the reference of xmorgrt.dll in the project also when I execute the solution it shown the JVM not loaded error, can you please share the correct version of xmorgrt dll one I am having is 1630 KB size, or tell me in case I am doing anything wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: xmorgrt.dll should be part of bin directory, you will not be able to add reference for xmorgrt.dll.

Comment: Hiren is correct: you should not be referencing xmorgrt. As for the JVM not loading, that is probably related to incomplete configuration. Follow the steps in the documentation for installing it.